# Was Slavery Ever Abolished on Tatooine?

Tags: star-wars

By reading the [Wookieepedia article on Tatooine](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tatooine), it's seen that the planet undergoes numerous changes in leadership. I can't, however, find any reference to slavery being outlawed.

We know from *The Phantom Menace* that the Republic at the time had anti-slavery laws, but Tatooine was not under the control of the Republic. It later became <del>under the control of</del> allied with the Galactic Empire, but seeing as they're the *badies*, I wouldn't be surprised if they were OK with slavery.

Anakin mentions in Episode I that he dreams about one day becoming a Jedi and freeing all the slaves. Unfortunately, he never gets to do this.

Did it ever happen, or did slavery continue on Tatooine?

Comment: "I wouldn't be surprised if they were OK with slavery." - The empire had slaves, mon calamari and wookies at the least.

Comment: @Kevin - This is definitely the first time I have ever seen a mod making the mistake of leaving a comment as an answer.  :)

Comment: @WadCheber to be fair, I posted it just a few months after I joined, well before I became a mod.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In 8 ABY, New Republic Senate Resolution 54.325 was issued [outlawing slavery](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Slavery) throughout the galaxy.  However, some outer-rim systems (possibly Tatooine to some extent) still had a slave trade of sorts run by the Hutts.  In 44 ABY, with the help of extensive holonet coverage, (and the Sith oddly enough) these systems rebelled against their masters.  Eventually, the Jedi stepped in to ensure rights of sentience.

Answer (score 5):

Not on Tatooine, at least not permanently (with the possible exception of the period mentioned in [demanufacture's answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/10977/976)).

All the info is gleaned from [the Wookieepedia article on Tatooine](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tatooine)

- It was always a major base (and briefly, during Vong war, a main home) for the Hutts. They wouldn't be too keen on abolishing slavery.
- It later fell under Galactic Alliance control. G.A. was supportive of slavery (it even caused the conflict with the Jedi later on)
- Even later, it was under tenuous control of Darth Krayt's New Galactic Empire. Same story as with the original Empire - tacit support for slavery from the main structure, with Hutts not really complaining locally.