# Was Anakin's dream a Force-vision?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In Episode I, Anakin tells Qui-Gon that he dreamed he was a Jedi:

> **Anakin:** I had a dream I was a Jedi. I came back here and freed all the
>   slaves...have you come to free us?

We take from Episode II and III that Anakin has a great amount of visions. Since the Force is so strong in him, and it was being manifest on its own (eg. piloting a pod-race at the age of 9, for example)...

...Was that dream a true [Force-vision](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_vision) that was somehow disrupted by his turning to the Dark Side?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Was Slavery Ever Abolished on Tatooine?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/was-slavery-ever-abolished-on-tatooine)

Comment: @Richard - That question has absolutelly nothing to do with mine...

Comment: I don't understand this question. Either Anakin dreamed something that happened (in which case it obviously was a dream of the future) or he dreamed something that didn't happen (in which case it obviously *wasn't* a dream of the future).

Comment: @Null - That's why I quoted Yoda... The future is in motion, something maybe predicted to happen, and due to some different decisions, they happen differently...

Comment: @Null If I dream that I have breakfast tomorrow, and then I do in fact have breakfast, that doesn't make it a vision of the future. I think the question is whether there's any precognition involved, ensuring that it was a true vision, rather than just being a lucky coincidence.

Comment: But it's not the future to us anymore. We know that Anakin did *not* return to Tatooine and free the slaves so it could not have been a dream from the future. This looks like a "what if" question: "what if Anakin hadn't turned to the dark side, would he have freed the slaves on Tatooine?"

Comment: @MikeScott I suppose that depends on how "vision" is defined. A lucky coincidence could still be considered a "vision".

Comment: @Null - No, it's not a *what if* question. MikeScott's right. The question is about the relation of his dream with the Force. Think about it: The boy has the higher count of midichlorians ever seen. He can pilot a podrace at the age of 9. Is it so weird to think that his dream about being a Jedi is influenced by the Force?

Comment: That clears up this question slightly -- you're asking about him becoming a Jedi, not freeing the slaves as both @Richard and I interpreted it. But, again, we know Anakin's future -- the vision turned out to be partially true (he became a Jedi) and partially false (he did not free the slaves). Since it turned out to be partially false it seems obvious that the dream was not influenced by the Force. It is easily explained as the wishful dream of a slave boy to become a powerful and respected Jedi.

Comment: @Null I don't think the question has anything to do with either becoming a Jedi or freeing the slaves.  It has to do with the dream itself.  I believe OP wants to know if the dream was a vision, regardless of whether either came true.

Comment: @DaveJohnson - It needs rephrasing. As it stands, it's a dupe.

Comment: Ok everyone... I editted the question. Not exactly what I had in mind, but made it simpler (I hope)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unlikely.**

- In the period between being freed himself and the point that he returned to Tatooine, Anakin seems to have shown little or no interest in freeing the slaves of his homeworld (not least including his own mother).
- Had he not turned to the Dark Side of the Force, he would have probably become a Jedi Master in his own right. The Jedi as an organisation seem to have little or no interest in curtailing slavery outside the core worlds of the Republic.

Frankly, these seem to be the idle fantasies of a small slave boy.

Comment: I'd like to see "some kind of canon reference" for this. :)

Comment: @Null - Both points of supposition are based on the events of the Star Wars prequels. You can't get much more canon.

Comment: I know. I agree with you -- I made some of the same points in the comments. I'm just teasing you for your comment to my [answer about Palpatine allowing himself to be kidnapped](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/73850/31936).

Comment: @Null - http://i.imgur.com/GcD3yca.gif