# Did Palpatine push Anakin and Padme together?

Tags: star-wars, anakin-skywalker, padme

Palpatine obviously spends time manipulating the both of them separately to do what he wants. For example, with Padme he pushes her to call for a vote of no confidence and with Anakin he uses his emotions to bend him to his side.

Now with him using Anakin's emotions to bend his will it would make sense for him to want him to care for someone. As far as I know he knew that Anakin had feelings for Padme.

Did he ever try and push them together, romantically, to try and aid pushing Anakin towards him?

Comment: Palpatine's reaction to Anak in wanting to save her life certainly appealed to Anakin more than Yoda's suggestion "Train yourself to let go of everything you fear to lose."

Comment: Do you mean physically?

Comment: @Verdan No-one ever listens to Yoda.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - That's because he talks like a weirdo.

Comment: If he has, he should've told Anakin about how sand and flirting don't really mix.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/73849/51379

Comment: Good guy Palpatine. Finds a girl for little Annie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Possibly.

He was the one who suggested that additional (Jedi) security be put in place for Padmé. He also personally suggested that Obi-Wan be assigned to the case, which is what brought Padmé and Anakin together again (since Obi-Wan and Anakin come as a pair).

> **PADMÉ:** Chancellor, please! I don't want any more guards!
>   **PALPATINE:** I realise all too well that additional security might be disruptive for you, but perhaps someone you are familiar with... an old friend like... Master Kenobi...
>   PALPATINE nods to MACE WINDU, who nods back.
>   **MACE WINDU:** That's possible. He has just returned from a Border dispute on Ansion.
>   <sub>*(Star Wars, Episode II: Attack of the Clones)*.</sub>

So Palpatine helped reintroduce Anakin to Padmé. If he hadn't have done so they could not have formed a relationship. However, they primarily fell in love on Naboo when Obi-Wan wasn't around. The decision to send Anakin on that mission and leave on Obi-Wan on Coruscant to investigate the mystery of the bounty hunter seems to have been taken by the Jedi Council.

> **PADMÉ:** I do not like this idea of hiding.
>   **ANAKIN:** Don't worry. Now that the Council has ordered an investigation, it won't take Master Obi-Wan long to find that bounty hunter.
>   <sub>*(Star Wars, Episode II: Attack of the Clones)*.</sub>

Chances are, Palpatine was unaware of Anakin's relationship with Padmé until they'd already fallen in love. He certainly sensed an advantage in their relationship once it had started, however, and exploited it to full effect. It was because of Palpatine's staged kidnap by the Separatists that Anakin was brought back to Coruscant and to Padmé.

> **ANAKIN:** I'm back, I'm all right. It feels like we've been apart for a lifetime. And it might have been ... If the Chancellor hadn't been kidnapped. I don't think they would have ever brought us back from the Outer Rim sieges.
>   <sub>*(Star Wars, Episode III: Revenge of the Sith)*.</sub>

And, of course, he used Anakin's feelings for Padmé to convert him to the Dark Side of the Force.

> **PALPATINE:** Only through me can you achieve a power greater than any Jedi. Learn to know the dark side of the Force, Anakin, and you will be able to save your wife from certain death.
>   <sub>*(Star Wars, Episode III: Revenge of the Sith)*.</sub>

**So he had a hand in their coming together. But he probably didn't engineer their relationship.**

Comment: The implication from the novelisations and the new Tarkin novel is that Anakin and Palpatine were in touch *regularly* from the moment that they met.

Comment: @Valorum As in between I and II?

Comment: "*He needed to speak with Chancellor Palpatine again, to hear the man’s reassuring words. **Palpatine had taken a great interest in him over the last ten years, making sure that he always got a chance to speak with him whenever he and Obi-Wan were on Coruscant.***" - Attack of the Clones - Official Novelisation

Comment: @Valorum From the AotC script: "I haven’t seen her in ten years, master." Implies no contact either.

Comment: Yes, he wasn't in contact with Padmé

Comment: @Valorum Oh sorry, when you wrote Palpatine I read Padmé. Too many characters with Ps in their names.