# Was Tatooine part of the Galactic Republic before the Clone Wars?

Tags: star-wars, planets

[This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10974/was-slavery-ever-abolished-on-tatooine) seems to assume that Tatooine allowed slavery because it wasn't part of the Galactic Republic.  I'm not sure about that.  Wookieepedia doesn't address the issue, merely reinforcing the ideas that (1) slavery existed there, and (2) Tatooine eventually joined the Empire.

Let's clear this up:

### Did Tatooine ever belong to the (pre-Imperial) republic, and if so, when did it join?

*Note 1:  Canon answers are STRONGLY preferred over Legends*

*Note 2:  Bonus points if you can provide a link to a list of worlds known to have been part of the republic*

Answer (score 59):

Apparently not, according to this conversation between Qui-Gon Jinn and Shmi Skywalker where Qui-Gon states that Anakin was not born in the Republic (from the Episode I script) :

> SHMI: He deserves better than a slave's life.
>
> QUI-GON: Had he been born in the Republic, we would have identified him early. The Force is unusually strong with him, that much is clear.

Answer (score 16):

No. In the *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* movie, Palpatine says:

> The Hutts control the Outer Rim...and we'll need their space lanes in order to move our troops.

The relationship between the 2 parties is written in galactic law by the [Hutt-Republic treaty](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hutt%E2%80%93Republic_treaty)

Answer (score 6):

**Not in any canon**. According to canon they are only affiliated with the Galactic Empire and the Hutt Clan, at least from what I could tell.

**In Legends** however, Tatooine was represented in the Galactic Senate during the Old Republic. And as I understand it Tatooine was unofficially allied with the Republic during parts of the Clone Wars and the Republic was allowed to have a spaceport there. Though this hardly qualifies as belonging to the Republic.

Even saying it was unofficially allied with the Republic might be a stretch. The reason I said that is because of Jabba, he let the Republic travel Hutt Space and with him being the arguably most powerful individual on the planet, I think you could say that Tatooine leaned against the Republic.

Does [this list of planets affiliated with the Republic](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Republic-aligned_planets?pageuntil=Dagro#mw-pages) meet your criteria?

Comment: What source do you have for Tatooine being represented in the Galactic Senate?